# How to merge two related branches

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

Let's suppose I'm working on a new feature called Feature1. I create a branch from develop, make all necessary commits, and wait for my PR to be approved. Meanwhile, I need to keep working on another new feature called Feature2, which requires some changes I added in Feature1. However, since Feature1 hasn't been approved, it hasn't been merged into develop. Therefore, I create the Feature2 branch from Feature1.

The question arises from this point, and I have two different paths, and I'd like to know if both are correct, which one is recommended, or which one is not.

[image]

Option 1: While I'm developing Feature2, Feature1 gets approved. In that case, I merge Feature1 into develop, delete the branch, and when I finish Feature2, I merge it into develop as well.

Option 2: Despite Feature1 being approved, I don't merge it. Instead, I wait until Feature2 is finished, merge it with Feature1 , and then merge Feature1 with develop, which already has the changes from Feature2.

Can I perform either of these options? Will one of them cause more problems than the other?

And when I want to do the merge, what is the best practice? Should I first bring the changes from develop to my current working branch, test that everything is working well, push the changes after merging to update the branch, and only then merge that branch into develop? Or should I merge my branch directly into develop?

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052772/github-creating-a-feature-branch-off-a-feature-branch) it is recommended to do a rebase, but can it be done with any of the methods presented in the example?

Comment: It depends where all this is happening.  PR is not a Git feature so what are we talking about? GitHub perhaps?

Comment: yes, working with github sorry